# My Apache HTTPD server and Tomcat Apache are on different machine, how will I configure it or form connection between them?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

My **Apache HTTPD server** web server is on IP *xxx.xx.15.46* and **Tomcat Apache** (Application server ) is on IP *xxx.xx.2.249*.

Whenever URL is hit through Internet, my URL should hit first to web server (Apache HTTPD server) and then to application server (Apache Tomcat). And unidirectional port is being opened between them.

But I am unable to form connection even after doing changes in **HTTPD.conf** of web server and **server.xml** file of Tomcat Apache. And even used **mod_jk** connector to establish connection between them.

How to configure Apache HTTPD server and Tomcat Apache Application server present on different machine?

Comment: Show the apache config file (part with redirect/mod_jk)

Comment: Can you please elaborate..

Comment: You want help, but provide information like "memories of witnesses". Read this document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask